# Tracking custom tfs build activity in workflow application

Tags: tfs, workflow-foundation-4, tracking, tfsbuild, workflow-activity

I'm developing a rather extensive library of custom build activities and created a workflow console application to speed up testing changes on that library. Now to further enhance the development process I would like to output the build workflow tracking messages to my console. The messages are generated in my custom activites like so:

```
context.TrackBuildMessage("Activity started.", BuildMessageImportance.High);
```

My first guess was creating a BuildTrackingParticipant and add it as extension to the invoker but I don't know how to initialize a BuildTrackingParticipant so it outputs its messages to the app console.

```
WorkflowInvoker invoker = new WorkflowInvoker(myWorkflow);
invoker.Extensions.Add(BuildTrackingParticipant);
invoker.Invoke();
```

Is there a way to make this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by *initialize a BuildTrackingParticipant*? Isn't `invoker.Extensions.Add(new BuildTrackingParticipant());` working for you?

Comment: BuildTrackingParticipant doesn't have an empty constructor. It needs lBuildDetail which I don't know how to get.

Comment: I can't really help you with tfsbuild process specifically. But since you're running your own test suite shouldn't you be implementing and injecting your own custom `IBuildDetail` with whatever dummy data you want?

Comment: Havn't implemented it into unit testing yet but could you give me an example or a link where I can cheat on how to implement a custom IBuildDetail dummy

Comment: Use you google skills: [Testing your TFS 2012 build workflow activities](http://www.vlaquest.com/2013/08/testing-your-tfs-2012-build-workflow-activities/). I can't help you more than this regarding tfs build workflows.